# C# SQL insert into Netezza. Netezza not sending return, c# code timing out

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, netezza

I'd really like some advice on this as I have been running into this issue quite a bit now. I have a couple applications, both big and small where I need to do some work with Netezza. Unfortunately, it seems a common issue with .net and Netezza, is Netezza takes a sql command, executes it (I have confirmed it in the log), but periodically does not send a return back, and my OLEDB connection in my C# app just sits there and times out. In the Netezza log I can also see that my session just sits there open, because my app is still waiting for NZ to send something back. This seems to happen only with a connection that executes more than 1 command.

Anyways, below is some code and I want some advice on how to mitigate this issue. I currently but in a retry count, but I'd really like something maybe more fail-safe. Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with an issue like this where you may not receive a return?

This particular loop is about 135 record updates, and only takes 1 minute normally. The lack of return isn't on any specific record. It's completely random and happens in other applications as well.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace RemoveVoidedInvoices
{
class UpdateNetezza
{
    public bool NetezzaWorkFailure = false;

    private void NetezzaWorkFailed()
    {
        NetezzaWorkFailure = true;
    }

    public void updateCounts(List<RecordCounts> recordCounts)
    {

        string connString = string.Format("Provider=NZOLEDB;Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=EBIDW;User ID=MYUSERNAME;Password={1}", Environment, passWord);

        OleDbConnection netezzaConn = null;

        //Due to timeout issues I am making a quick timespan entry so that I can keep track in the log of how long each day the bulk update took
        DateTime Prequery = DateTime.Now;
        int retrycount = 0;

        try
        {
            netezzaConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            netezzaConn.Open();

            for (int i = 0; i < recordCounts.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (recordCounts[i].RecordCount.ToString() != recordCounts[i].OrigCount.ToString())
                    {
                        string updateStatement = string.Format("UPDATE fct_ourtable SET LINESWRITTENTOFILE = {0} where EXTRACTFILENAME = '{1}' and LINESWRITTENTOFILE = {2}", recordCounts[i].RecordCount.ToString(), recordCounts[i].FileName, recordCounts[i].OrigCount.ToString());

                        Console.WriteLine("Executing query : " + updateStatement);
                        Console.WriteLine("Query start-time - " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        OleDbCommand exe = new OleDbCommand(updateStatement, netezzaConn);
                        exe.CommandTimeout = 2000;

                        int rowsUpdated;

                        rowsUpdated = exe.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Console.WriteLine("Rows Updated = " + rowsUpdated.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Query end-time - " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No records were removed from the file : " + recordCounts[i].FileName + ". Not updating Netezza.");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }

                catch (OleDbException oledbex)
                {
                    retrycount++;

                    if (retrycount > 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of retrys met. Canceling now.");
                        throw new System.Exception();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = i - 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Timeout on Query, retrying");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                NetezzaWorkFailed();
        }

        finally
        {
            if (netezzaConn != null)
            {
                netezzaConn.Close();
                netezzaConn = null;
            }
            TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Prequery);
            Console.WriteLine("Query Time: " + duration);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This may be more appropriate as a comment but I don't have enough rep.*

I haven't used OleDB much but we run queries in a similar manner to what you're doing with ODBC and haven't had any issues. It would be interesting to try at least.

A few comments on your snippet, which I doubt will have much effect on your problem but will help clarify and shorten the code.

- Call `Dispose` instead of `Close` on your connection.
- Also `Dispose` your command object.
- Use parameters instead of formatting a query string (works for [OleDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ODCB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)). Create your OleDBCommand outside the loop and add your three parameters. Inside the loop you set the `Value` of the parameters and execute the query as you do already.
- Use `using` blocks instead of `try`-`catch` to avoid the explicit calls to `Dispose`. You will still need a `try`-`catch` block inside or outside the `using` block if you want to handle exceptions.